# Como deixar o vim dessa forma?

Tags: vim

Gostaria de configurar o meu vim para deixar como na imagem.

Já tenho o MacVim instalado.

A minha maior necessidade é o explorador de arquivos.

[image: vim personalizado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O explorador de arquivos é o plugin [The NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree).

A barra de status é provavelmente o [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline).

Quanto ao tema, recomendo dar uma olhada [aqui](http://vimcolors.com/), tem vários temas bacanas.

Se quiser saber algo mais, é só falar.